# Lookup fields on a custom object seem to be missing?

Tags: custom-object, lookup

My org has a custom object - call it `Wario__c` - with two lookup fields. It can be the child of either a `Lead` or a `Contact` object.

In the **Custom Object Definition** for `Wario`, it displays `Contact (Contact__c)` and `Lead (Lead__c)` under the header "Custom Fields & Relationships."

[image: Custom Fields & Relationships for Wario__c]

So far, so good. In the page layout, the Contact and Lead fields are "in use" and located prominently on the page.

But in actual, instantiated objects, there's no `Contact` and no `Lead` displayed. I can't query `Wario__c.Contact__c` or `Wario__c.Lead__c`, nor can I reach (for instance) `Wario__c.Contact__r.Id`.

And when I look in the Workbench, the Contact__c and Lead__c fields are missing.

[image: Workbench view of fields on Wario__c]

What might be going on here? Why can't I see or query the lookup fields on this object?

Comment: Feels like you may not have permissions to the fields. If that is the case  you won't see them or  be able to query them (you won't see them via workbench either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feels like you may not have permissions to the fields. If that is the case you won't see them or be able to query them (you won't see them via workbench either).

Click on the fields, then click on "Set Field Level Security" and ensure your profile can see them.

Comment: My Lord. We relied on an external consultant to create the object, and had a lot of problems with them. It never even occurred to me that they would have removed visibility for the admin profile...

Comment: I am sorry. Those consultants exist. Come back here any time you need more help!